# How to link to to page in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using paperclip and rails.  I followed this tutorial:
[Multiple File Uploads with Paperclip & Rails 3 (Screencast)](http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/paperclip-with-rails-3)

I have a gallery model that has many galleryphotos.

Instead of linking to the original image in my view, I created a show method in photoimage, but I get the the following error:

```
undefined method `galleryphoto_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f40a0000c20>:0x00000005385d60>
```

Here is my code:

```
<% for asset in gallery.galleryphotos %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(asset.photo.url(:thumb)), url_for(asset) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my galleryphoto controller:

```
class GalleryphotosController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
    @galleyphoto = @gallery.galleyphotos.find(params[:id])


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @gallery }
    end
  end
 end
```

Here are my routes for these:

```
  resources :galleries do
    resources :galleryphotos
  end
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: So is the show method in a PhotoImagesController ? (but the model is called galleryphoto)? Want to make sure I have that right.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - yes correct.    My controller is GalleyphotosController

Comment: is this represented in your routes.rb file?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - Added mu controller code

Comment: @Rabbott - Yes, see the routes code I added

Comment: @bigdaveyl please mark the answer as correct if it is the correct one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url_for` helper will not find a route for the `Galleryphoto` model because it depends on the `Gallery` model. It is declared in the routes as a nested resource, so a `Galleryphoto` does not exist without a `Gallery` in the url.

To fix this do any of the following:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(asset.photo.url(:thumb)), url_for(gallery, asset) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to image_tag(asset.photo.url(:thumb)), gallery_galleryphoto_path(gallery, asset) %>
```

Comment: this gets me closer.  The links show up on my gallery page.  The 2nd solution works.  However, I get this error in my controller now:  NoMethodError in GalleryphotosController#show

undefined method `galleyphotos' for #<Gallery:0x000000050239b0>

Comment: @bigdaveyl that is an unrelated error. It is happenning because your `Gallery` model does not have a `:has_many :galleryphotos` or it is named differently.

Comment: That's not it.  I'll post another question